# Using Logstash as shipper?

Tags: monitoring, logging, redis, logstash, elasticsearch

We are shipping logs from servers and using THE logstash on each server for shipping.

So we read logs from the glob `"/root/Desktop/Logstash-Input/**/*_log"`.

```
 input {
            file{
                    path => "/root/Desktop/Logstash-Input/**/*_log"
                    start_position => "beginning"
            }
    }
```

From this glob we extract *fields* from the `path` which we want added to the event. Eg: from the directory `path` extract the `server`, `logtype`, etc. We do this:

```
filter {

grok {

        match => ["path", "/root/Desktop/Logstash-Input/(?<server>[^/]+)/(?<logtype>[^/]+)/(?<logdate>[\d]+.[\d]+.[\d]+)/(?<logfilename>.*)_log"]
}
}
```

And then we output these logs to the central logstash server using `lumberjack` output plugin.

```
output {

        lumberjack {
                hosts => ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]
                port => 4545
                ssl_certificate => "./logstash.pub"
    }

        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Problem is that logs shipped to the central server loose the fields added using `grok`. Eg `server`, `logtype`, etc are not present on central server. However, client machine console shows the fields added but on central logstash server only `message`, `timestamp` , `version` is present.

**Client (from where logs are shipped) console:**

```
output received {:event=>{"message"=>"2014-05-26T00:00:01+05:30 host crond[268]: (root) CMD (2014/05/31/server2/cron/log)", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2014-07-16T06:07:21.927Z", "host"=>"host", "path"=>"/root/Desktop/Logstash-Input/Server2/CronLog/2014.05.31/cron_log", "server"=>"Server2", "logtype"=>"CronLog", "logdate"=>"2014.05.31", "logfilename"=>"cron"}, :level=>:debug, :file=>"(eval)", :line=>"37"}
    {
              "message" => "2014-05-26T00:00:01+05:30 bx920as1 crond[268]: (root) CMD (2014/05/31/server2/cron/log)",
             "@version" => "1",
           "@timestamp" => "2014-07-16T06:07:21.927Z",
                 "host" => "host",
                 "path" => "/root/Desktop/Logstash-Input/Server2/CronLog/2014.05.31/cron_log",
               "server" => "Server2",
              "logtype" => "CronLog",
              "logdate" => "2014.05.31",
          "logfilename" => "cron"
    }
```

**Central Server (where logs are shipped to) console**:

```
{
       "message" => "2014-07-16T05:33:17.073+0000 host 2014-05-26T00:00:01+05:30 bx920as1 crond[288]: (root) CMD (2014/05/31/server2/cron/log)",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-07-16T05:34:02.370Z"
}
```

So the grokked fields are dropped while shipping. Why is it so??

How can I retain the fields??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I solved it by adding `codec => "json"` to my lumberjack output and input.

**Output:**

```
output {

    lumberjack {
            hosts => ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]
            port => 4545
            ssl_certificate => "./logstash.pub"
            codec => "json"
}
```

**Input:**

```
input { 
    lumberjack {
        port => 4545
        ssl_certificate => "/etc/ssl/logstash.pub"
        ssl_key => "/etc/ssl/logstash.key"  
        codec => "json"
  }
}
```